# cannot change the row background duing dynamic insert the row into datagrid

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I use jQuery to add the new row on datagrid after the page load. It successfully added the new row, but the background color didn't change (it used the same color as the last row). Would someone tell me how to solve it.

This is my query:

```
 function jQueryTest() {             

     $('.hideClass').each(function() {                 
         var $clone = $('#ref').clone().data("arr", [1]);
         $clone.toggleClass('hide', false);
         $clone.addClass('show');                              
         $(this).css("background-color", "blue");              
         //$('<tr bgcolor="black"><td colspan="18"> <span style="background-                            color:#9999ff;">
               <font color="red">*test</font></td></tr></span>').insertAfter($(this).parent());

         $('<tr bgcolor=="#FF0000"><td colspan="18" bgcolor="#00FF00"><span style="background- 
           color: #9999ff;"><font color="red">** test</font></td></tr></span>').insertAfter
            ($(this).parent());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After I change the code to the bellows and it worked

```
 $('<tr width=100%;><td colspan="18" bgcolor="#00FF00"><div  style="background-color: #9999ff;"><font color="red">*test </font></div></td></tr>').insertAfter($(this).parent());
```